# Adding from child route to parent template

Tags: angular

Lets say I am creating a shopping website. I want to show a shopping cart in the master templates header. The shopping cart should be shown only in the shopping pages, and not other pages. For example payment page should not have that.

Now I cannot find how I can inject something to the master template - in this case the shopping cart - when from inside a child component. In other words, how should I make a placeholder in master template, and populate it from child

Answer (score 0):

```
app component -> <router-outlet />

route: /shopping-page -> <cart /><router-outlet />
  child routes: /shopping-page/:item -> <child-content />

route: /payment-page -> <payment-content />
```

as structured above, create a route for wrapper component for the pages with the common component that contains the common component and a router-outlet and declare all the pages as children of that route and only populate those templates with the non common content.

Then stick whatever you want in the routes for pages that don't need the common component.

You're not populating the master content from the child, the templates are just appropriately nested.

Comment: But they are not quite nested you see. Shopping cart is a small piece in the header, and <router-outlet/> is in the body.

Comment: the actual screen location is irrelevant, you structure the templates in this nested structure to provide the common component where it is needed. Then use CSS / HTML to position as needed.